# How to efficiently send the same message to thousands of clients using ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want to *efficiently* send the same message to thousands of clients using Artemis ActiveMQ.  I'm using the core interface currently, but am open to whichever interface works.

According to [the docs](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/migration-documentation/key-differences.html):

> Multicast routing is used to implement publish-subscribe semantics, where all subscribers to a certain address will get their own internal queue and messages will be routed to all of them.

Having each subscriber be implemented with its own queue seems bad when there are that many subscribers and the content being sent is exactly the same.  That seems like a classic case for UDP.  ActiveMQ has some [limited documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/udp-transport-reference) that indicates support for UDP, but I don't see the same thing for Artemis.

Can UDP be used a transport for Artemis?  Is there a different way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find any reference to a UDP transport in the ActiveMQ Artemis [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/) because it's not supported.

In fact, I don't know of any major messaging protocol (e.g. AMQP, STOMP, MQTT) that can be implemented over UDP. They all require a reliable transport like TCP. Although the JMS specification only describes an API and doesn't specify how the wire protocol should be implemented it envisions the use of reliable transport like TCP. There *is* a variant of MQTT called MQTT-SN which uses UDP, but [the specification](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/document.php?document_id=66091&wg_abbrev=mqtt) is still in the draft state.

In any case, the network transport which the client uses wouldn't change the fundamental operation of the broker. The underlying [address model](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html) would still be the same.

The way the broker works is pretty efficient even in the multicast use-case with a large number of queues & clients. For example:

- Queues are relatively light-weight.
- The content of each message is only stored once and each queue gets a "reference" to the message.
- Internal byte buffers are pooled which reduces byte copying.

I could go on, but you probably get the general idea. The broker is designed for efficiency and speed. It should support you use-case without much (if any) trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Justin.  That saves me time searching for something that doesn't exist.  I guess UDP was supported in AMQ but not Artemis?  Am I correct in thinking that Artemis having individual queues for 5,000 - 10,000 subscribers would increase the network traffic by 5,000 - 10,000 times over a UDP implementation (assuming that all clients receive the same messages)?

Comment: Regarding your first question...Technically it is possible to use UDP in ActiveMQ "Classic," but I've never actually seen it done since UDP is fundamentally unreliable. [The documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/udp-transport-reference) even says, "Note that by default UDP is not reliable; datagrams can be lost so you should add a reliability layer to ensure the JMS contract can be implemented on a non-reliable transport." I imagine that most folks consider adding a "reliability layer" to be impractical when TCP can simply be used instead.

Comment: Regarding your second question...I'm not a network expert so I can't say how TCP vs. UDP would ultimately impact traffic in this use-case. The unreliability of UDP would certainly force repeated transmission of the same data by some "reliability layer" which, to my knowledge, hasn't actually been implemented. The extra communication required to implement reliability would also increase traffic for the UDP use-case, likely by a non-trivial amount.